# Use index 0 subindexes of an array as keys for a hash in a data table

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

currently I’m working on this little code. I need to use the 0 index as the keys, then the next elements need to appear as values such as in the following example:

```
[{"Nombre"=>"Rodrigo García", "Edad"=>13, 
"Genero"=>"Masculino", "Grupo"=>"Primero", "Calificaciones"=>[9, 9, 7, 6, 
 8]},... #for each one of the people represented in the table
```

I’ve tried to use zip as well as transpose but I can’t do it from only one array. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance!

```
table = [["Nombre","Edad","Genero","Grupo","Calificaciones"],
        ["Rodrigo Garcia",13,"Masculino","Primero",[9, 9, 7, 6, 8]],
        ["Fernanda Gonzalez",12,"Femenino","Tercero",[6, 9, 8, 6, 8]],
        ["Luis Perez",13,"Masculino","Primero",[8, 7, 7, 9, 8]],
        ["Ana Espinosa",14,"Femenino","Segundo",[9, 9, 6, 8, 8]],
        ["Pablo Moran",11,"Masculino","Segundo",[7, 8, 9, 9, 8]]]

p Hash[table.zip]
puts
puts
p table.transpose
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you may need to do some refactoring if you're going to work with large data sets, anyways:

```
head  = ["Nombre","Edad","Genero","Grupo","Calificaciones"]
table = [["Rodrigo Garcia",13,"Masculino","Primero",[9, 9, 7, 6, 8]],
        ["Fernanda Gonzalez",12,"Femenino","Tercero",[6, 9, 8, 6, 8]],
        ["Luis Perez",13,"Masculino","Primero",[8, 7, 7, 9, 8]],
        ["Ana Espinosa",14,"Femenino","Segundo",[9, 9, 6, 8, 8]],
        ["Pablo Moran",11,"Masculino","Segundo",[7, 8, 9, 9, 8]]]

ret = table.map {|row| head.zip(row) }

# or maybe better, convert to a hash, to retrieve data more easily.

ret2= table.map {|row| head.zip(row).to_h }

puts ret   #=> [[["Nombre", "Rodrigo Garcia"], ["Edad", 13], ["Genero", "Masculino"]...
puts re2   #=> [{"Nombre"=>"Rodrigo Garcia", "Edad"=>13, "Genero"=>"Masculino", ...
```

Comment: If the input is not in control of the user, then you could do `head = table.shift`.